# Issues with two forms of Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Recently I installed a second version of Python on my Jupyter notebook so that I could either use Python 2 or 3 when I wanted to. However, after installing Python 3, I ran into an issue with matplotlib, scipy, and numpy on my previous python2 notebooks.

Typing:

```
%pylab inline
import time
import datetime
import glob
import os
from os import system
import platform
import scipy.ndimage as snd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
```

gave me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fe04d06772cd> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'pylab inline')
      2 import time
      3 import datetime
      4 import glob
      5 import os

/Users/stephanng/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2334         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2335         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2336         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2337 
   2338     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/stephanng/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2255                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2256             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2257                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2258             return result
   2259 

<decorator-gen-107> in pylab(self, line)

/Users/stephanng/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/Users/stephanng/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in pylab(self, line)
    154             import_all = not args.no_import_all
    155 
--> 156         gui, backend, clobbered = self.shell.enable_pylab(args.gui, import_all=import_all)
    157         self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    158         print ("Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib")

/Users/stephanng/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all, welcome_message)
   3169         from IPython.core.pylabtools import import_pylab
   3170 
-> 3171         gui, backend = self.enable_matplotlib(gui)
   3172 
   3173         # We want to prevent the loading of pylab to pollute the user's

/Users/stephanng/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3118         """
   3119         from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 3120         gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
   3121 
   3122         if gui != 'inline':

/Users/stephanng/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    237     """
    238 
--> 239     import matplotlib
    240 
    241     if gui and gui != 'auto':

ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

What I get from this is that Python 2 is no longer pointing to the correct directory when looking at imports.  How do I go about setting the path to the correct directory?

Answer (score 2):

I completely uninstalled everything and then reinstalled it and the paths were corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common problem that different python use-cases require different installations. To avoid the crosstalk you can use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/%22)  to keep your installations separate.

Comment: I actually uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything and it seemed to keep both versions and link up to the proper imports...so all good!